# How can I make this image responsive to page size without the text on it moving

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my page looks fine in a desktop, but when I look at it through any other device, (phone, tablet) the text on the page has moved lower into the other content. Is there a way to make it so that the text shrinks as the image does?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="hero">
        <img src="resources/assets/home_header.png" alt="youth futures header"/>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Hi</h1>
                <p class="textstyle2">14 WARM BEDS. YOUTH 12-17.<br/>YOUR TEMPORARY HOME:)</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.hero {
 width:1280px;
  margin:0rem auto;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:0;
padding:1rem;
transform:translateY(-50%);
text-align:center !important;
margin: 0px 197px 103px 531px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use media queries to reduce the font sizes on small screens

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I am not familiar with media queries, do you have an example?

Comment: added to my answer